# Is Interface Builder supposed to be very slow?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm running a mid-2015 15" RMBP with 16GB RAM and a 2.5Ghz i7, yet Xcode really chugs along whenever I open or change a storyboard or XIB. I'm using a lot of IBDesignable classes...is IB normally beach ball city, or could there be another problem?

Comment: No, they're in the same project. That's very helpful I will look into it and get back to this thread if it helps. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

While Xcode doesn't force us to, Apple instructs us that designables should be in a separate target (e.g. "File" - "New" - "Target..." - "Cocoa Touch Framework"). For more information, see WWDC 2014 video [What's New in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/411/).

Note, that doesn't need to be a separate project. Using the same project is fine, but the designables need to be in separate framework target within that project. Xcode needs to be able to compile that designables target separately, and if it's part of the main target, you'll be doing a lot of unnecessary re-compiling. Worse, I've seen people report degenerate situations where it's constantly recompiling, too. As that video will show you, a separate framework target within your project is all you'll need.

Comment: Not sure if you remembered a different video, but there's nothing like that in the WWDC presentation you linked. I'm messing with the idea though...not quite clear on how this should be organized. Once you add a target, do you move the class files into the new target's folder, or is it enough to just have the file in the new target's "Compile Sources"?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's WWDC 2014 video [What's New in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/411/). It's in the discussion of "Live Views".

Comment: Thanks. It's late here now but I'll definitely give it a watch tomorrow.

Comment: It's not really clear that it's making a difference TBH. Do you have to configure some build setting? That video doesn't really explain *why* you should put the designables in a framework. Can't find any documentation on it either. Maybe instead I was just supposed to turn off automatic view refresh in IB?

Comment: No, they don't really articulate why, but they are very specific. And it does (a) reduces the number of times it has to recompile; (b) reduces the amount of code to compile simply for the designables to be rendered; and (c) minimizes problems arising from project not being compilable state when you go to IB. I've certainly enjoyed performance benefits in putting designables in separate target.

Comment: All that said, it sounds like you've got other issues. And IB is certainly the slowest tool within Xcode (e.g., on my old iMac, it's unbearably slow; but my Mid 2014 RMBA (2.4 GHz i7; 16 GB; SSD) it's pretty reasonable). Also, I assume you've done the standard purging of derived data folder and rebooting on machine?

Comment: Something is wrong with the storyboard after refactoring all my views into frameworks. The storyboard is filled with about a hundred warnings that are variations of "UIView not key-value compliant", "Image not found", etc. Seems to be corrupted...a new storyboard works fine. MAJOR inconvenience. 

How exactly does the build process work with frameworks? I did some searching around, and the only rationale I could find for using frameworks for IBDesignable views was that there was simply no other way in Xcode6. Are you sure this isn't just some arbitrary old requirement?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know if this "use separate framework target" is, strictly speaking, a _requirement_ or merely just a best practice, but I really do think you want to use a framework target for designables. You don't want to have to have Xcode compile your whole app just to render a single designable in IB. I suspect your painful transition is a result that the designable wasn't originally placed in a separate target, as advised by Apple, when you first created the storyboard.

Comment: I know that's little solace for you at this point, but I think that if you're careful to use separate framework target for designables in the future, you'll be much happier.